# emailAddress autofillHints not filling in

Tags: android

I thought I had set up autofillHints properly in my app, but recently I noticed something strange. The login screen has two fields: email address and password. If I tap in the password field, the autofill prompt (I'm using LastPass) will appear. If I select an account, it will fill in the password, but will NOT fill in the email address. The password field changed color to indicate it had used autofill, but the email address field was untouched.

I could have sworn it worked properly in the past, but perhaps I was mistaken. I tried setting `android:importantForAutofill="yes"`, but that made no difference. I tried setting `emailEditText.setAutofillHints(View.AUTOFILL_HINT_EMAIL_ADDRESS)` in code instead of `android:autofillHints="emailAddress"` in XML, but that didn't change it.

I should be able to tap in either the email or password field and have the autofill prompt appear. Both fields should change color. Both fields should fill in.

Interestingly, if I change the `android:autofillHints` attribute of the email field to `password`, it does fill in. With the password, of course, not the email. But at least then the autofill service is doing something.

Answer (score 8):

I was completely lost until I stumbled across:

> One problem you may run into is that not all autofill services are
>   capable of filling the same types of content. While Google’s autofill
>   service can fill in credentials, addresses, phone numbers, credit card
>   information, and more, Dashlane only supports credentials (at the time
>   of writing this article).
>   from https://medium.com/@bherbst/getting-androids-autofill-to-work-for-you-21435debea1

That got me thinking. Perhaps LastPass isn't set up to fill in all fields. Perhaps it sees email address as a general form field (like phone number) instead of part of the login. Perhaps it's expecting something else instead.

I looked at the types of hints again. This time I tried `android:autofillHints="username"` and it worked perfectly. For login fields, `username` is the right hint type, not `emailAddress`, even when it is an email address.

Hope this saves someone else from the hassle I endured to figure this out!